Как сделать multi-touch в libGdx?
Делаю двумерную игру с видом сверху, камера привязана к персонажу игрока. Суть управления такова: касаешься слева от персонажа - задействуется джойстик, касаешься справа - персонаж атакует. Но возникла проблема - я не могу одновременно и двигать джойстик, и атаковать.
Код метода с отрисовкой:
@Override
    public void render(float delta) {
        // касания

        touchHandler();

        // события

        player.changePhase();

        // отрисовка
        ScreenUtils.clear(0, 0, 0, 0);
        debugRenderer.render(world, camera.combined);
        batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
        camera.position.set(player.getX(), player.getY(), 0);
        camera.update();
        batch.begin();

        wallBatch();

        doorPreBatch();

        playerBatch();

        doorPostBatch();

        joystick.render(batch, imgJstBase, imgJstKnob, player.getX() - SCR_WIDTH / 2.75f, player.getY() - SCR_HEIGHT / 4);
        batch.draw(imgJstBase, player.getX()+btnAttack.x, player.getY() - btnAttack.y, btnAttack.width, btnAttack.height);

        batch.end();

        world.step(1 / 60f, 6, 2);
    }

и код самого touchHandler:
if (Gdx.input.isTouched()) {
            touch.set(Gdx.input.getX(), Gdx.input.getY(), 0);
            camera.unproject(touch);
            if (touch.x < player.getX()) {
                joystick.updateKnob(touch);
                player.getBody().setLinearVelocity(
                        joystick.getDirectionVector().x * player.getSpeed(),
                        joystick.getDirectionVector().y * player.getSpeed()
                );
                if (Math.abs(joystick.getDirectionVector().x) > Math.abs(joystick.getDirectionVector().y)) {
                    if (joystick.getDirectionVector().x > 0) player.setDirection('r');
                    else player.setDirection('l');
                } else {
                    if (joystick.getDirectionVector().y > 0) player.setDirection('u');
                    else player.setDirection('d');
                }
            }
        } else {
            joystick.resetKnob();
            player.getBody().setLinearVelocity(0, 0);
        }

"touch" - это объект типа Vector3.
Пробовал разобраться и обращаться по индексу, но окончательно запутался и координаты touch.x, touch.y получались заоблачные (от -75000 до двух с чёртиком миллионов)

Хорошо проспавшись, я наконец это сделал (вроде как). Так что, если кому нужен код:
private void touchHandler(){
    actJoystick = false;
    actAttack = false;
    ArrayList<Vector3> touches = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        touches.add(new Vector3());
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        if (Gdx.input.isTouched(i)) {
            touches.get(i).set(Gdx.input.getX(i), Gdx.input.getY(i), 0);
            camera.unproject(touches.get(i));

            if (touches.get(i).x < player.getX()) {
                actJoystick = true;
                joystick.updateKnob(touches.get(i));
            }
            else if (touches.get(i).x > player.getX()) {
                actAttack = true;
            }
        }
    }

    if (actJoystick) {
        Vector2 directionVector = joystick.getDirectionVector();
        player.getBody().setLinearVelocity(
                directionVector.x * player.getSpeed(),
                directionVector.y * player.getSpeed()
        );
        if (Math.abs(directionVector.x) > Math.abs(directionVector.y)) {
            if (directionVector.x > 0) player.setDirection('r');
            else player.setDirection('l');
        } else {
            if (directionVector.y > 0) player.setDirection('u');
            else player.setDirection('d');
        }
    } else {
        joystick.resetKnob();
        player.getBody().setLinearVelocity(0, 0);
    }

    if (actAttack) {
// Атака!
    }
}
``


Я сделал следующим образом:
при инициализации main loop создают кастомный InputProcessor,
в процессоре есть пул, который хранит активные нажатия кнопок и прикосновений (это разные события)
public Game(ExampleGame game) {
    isDebugEnabled = false;
    this.game = game;

    exampleGameStage = new ExampleGameInputProcessor(game);
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(exampleGameStage);
...

внутри основного цикла будет доступен список кнопок и тачей:
    player_ship.update(delta, exampleGameStage.keys, exampleGameStage.touches);

внутри метода update класса PlayerShip обработка выглядит как-то так:
public void update(float delta, Set<Integer> keys, HashMap<Integer, Vector2> touches) {
    for (Map.Entry<Integer, Vector2> touch : touches.entrySet()) {
...
    }
    for (Integer key : keys) {
           if (key == Input.Keys.LEFT) {
...

сам ExampleGameInputProcessor выглядит как-то так:
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector2;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector3;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Stage;
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.viewport.FitViewport;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class VoyagerInputProcessor extends Stage {
    public Set<Integer> keys;
    public HashMap<Integer, Vector2> touches;
    public VoyagerInputProcessor(Voyager3 game) {
        super(new FitViewport(game.WORLD_WIDTH, game.WORLD_HEIGHT, game.camera), game.spriteBatch);
        keys = new HashSet<>();
        touches = new HashMap<>();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean keyDown(int keyCode) {
        super.keyDown(keyCode);
        keys.add(keyCode);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean keyUp(int keyCode) {
        super.keyUp(keyCode);
        keys.remove(keyCode);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean touchUp(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
        super.touchUp(screenX, screenY, pointer, button);
        touches.remove(pointer);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
        super.touchDown(screenX, screenY, pointer, button);
        touches.put(pointer, uprojectTouch(screenX, screenY));
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean touchDragged(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer) {
        super.touchDragged(screenX, screenY, pointer);
        touches.put(pointer, uprojectTouch(screenX, screenY));
        return true;
    }

    private Vector2 uprojectTouch(int screenX, int screenY) {
        Vector3 position = new Vector3(screenX, screenY, 0);
        this.getCamera().unproject(position,
            this.getViewport().getScreenX(), this.getViewport().getScreenY(),
            this.getViewport().getScreenWidth(), this.getViewport().getScreenHeight()
        );
        return new Vector2(position.x, position.y);
    }
}

